# "Runter" als Fahrtrichtung

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ich habe heute in einem Gespräch wieder das Wort "runter" als Fahrtrichtung gehört und frage mich, was darunter vorzustellen ist. Meint man damit die Position des Ziels auf der Karte, relativ zum aktuellen Ort?
Hier der genaue Satz:

> Ich fahre Freitags immer her und Sonntags wieder nach Stuttgart
>   runter.

Ich habe das auch in Bezug auf bestimmte Orte in der Stadt auch schon gehört, dass etwas "oben" oder "unten" ist. Spielt hier die Höhe über dem Meeresspiegel eine Rolle? Beispiel:

> Wir treffen uns oben in der Schule.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bei *runter* / *unten* (und auch *hoch* / *oben*) im Bezug auf Ortsangaben sind beide Bedeutungen möglich.

- **Höhe über dem Meeresspiegel**: Gilt vor allem bei kurzen Distanzen und innerhalb abgegrenzter Gebiete, z. B. in Dörfern und Städten
- **Position auf der Karte**: Gilt eher bei großen Distanzen. *Unten* entspricht dabei dem Süden (auf der Karte unten) und dem entsprechend *oben* dem Norden. Die Höhe über dem Meerespiegel wird dabei ignoriert. Man fährt zum Beispiel von Karlsruhe (115 m ü. NHN) nach Freiburg (278 m ü. NHN) runter. Diese Bedeutung ist jedoch eher umgangssprachlich.

Meine Antwort spiegelt in erster Linie meine Erfahrungen aus meinem Sprachraum (Nordbaden) wieder. Die Erfahrungen der anderen Nutzer deuten jedoch darauf hin, dass es regionale Unterschiede gibt.

Comment: Meiner Erfahrung nach wird das oft nicht so genau gehandhabt. Ich habe auch schon Leute gehört die sagten, sie würden wieder gen Norden "runterfahren", wobei "runterfahren" dann einfach eine längere Fahrt andeutete.

Comment: +1, sowohl für die Antwort als auch für den Kommentar von @RudyVelthuis ;-) Ich fahre häufiger zwischen Nord- und Süddeutschland hin und her, und bin außerdem gelegentlich in kleinen Ortschaften in den Bergen. Kann die Antwort so bestätigen.

Comment: Ich wollte das gleiche schreiben, wie Rudy Velthuis. Gerade bei meinem ersten Beispiel befand sich der Standort, von dem mein Bekannter gesprochen hat ungefähr auf der gleichen Höhe, wie Stuttgart. Spricht man also, wenn man "runterfahren" sagt einfach von einer längeren Strecke und nicht unbedingt von der Position auf der Karte? Wenn ja, gibt es dafür eine Erklärung oder muss man das einfach so hinnehmen? :)

Comment: @Igor: ich persönlich kenne es eigentlich nur so wie von mir beschrieben. Allerdings kann ich mir gut vorstellen, dass es starke regionale Unterschiede gibt und manche es wie von dir beshrieben einfach für längere Strecken verwenden, ohne das es irgendetwas zur Bedeutung beiträgt

Answer (score 6):

In diesem Fall ist höchstwahrscheinlich "unten" auf der Karte gemeint, also Süden.

Man vergleiche die Bezeichnung "Down under" für Australien.

Analog könnte man auch hören "Ich fahre wieder hoch nach Hamburg".

Was oben/unten als Bezeichnung für Orte in der Stadt betrifft, wird es in der Regel um höher oder niedriger gelegene Stadtteile gehen, eventuell aber auch um die Himmelsrichtung. Eine allgmeine Aussage lässt sich da kaum treffen.

Answer (score 2):

Ich kenne das in allen denkbaren Redewendungen ohne sinnvollen oder nachvollziehbaren Bezug zu Höhen oder Richtungen.
"runter fahren" = hinfahren, "rauf fahren" = zurückfahren. Oder auch umgekehrt! Je nach Sprecher ist es nur Gewohnheit oder einen Hintergrund.

Dazu kommt dass man in Deutschland auf der Karte "rauf" fährt wenn man nach Norden fährt, aber auf Höhe bezogen ist es "runter".

Am besten ist es das überhaupt nicht näher zu interpretieren. Es ist meistens ein bedeutungsloser Zusatz.

Bei Stadtteilen ist es natürlich einfacher. Wenn die Straße zur Schule nach oben führt, fährt man "rauf zur Schule" und danach wieder "runter".

Comment: "Ich kenne das in allen denkbaren Redewendungen ohne sinnvollen oder nachvollziehbaren Bezug zu Höhen oder Richtungen." - Das habe ich bisher rein intuitiv auch eher so empfunden. Vielleicht ist das eine Besonderheit des schwäbischen Dialekts? :)

Comment: Die Steirer fahren aus dem Süden Österreichs nach Wien "runter", und die Wiener fahren in die Steiermark "runter". Ich glaube nicht, dass man da viel Logik suchen sollte.